# Is there an efficient way to find a specific entry among JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a piece of JSON that looks as such:

```
"people":[ 
    {"name":"dave", "id":"4", "extraInfo": {"hairColor":"red"}},
    {"name":"john", "id":"2", "extraInfo": {"hairColor":"black"}},
    {"name":"jim", "id":"5", "extraInfo": {"hairColor":"brown"}},...}
]
```

Name and HairColor Fields aren't unique to each entry, and let's say each entry can have other information in addition to the 3 in the example: I could have an entry that looks like

```
{"name":"dave", "id":"467", "siblings":"1", "lastName":"jones" "extraInfo": {"hairColor":"red", "eyes":"blue"}, "height":"5 feet"}
```

I want to find the id of a person who matches a specific name and hairColor. I though of iterating over each object looking for these fields, but is there a more efficient way, some tool perhaps, for doing this?

Comment: "*I though of iterating over each object looking for these fields, but is there a more efficient way*" unless you know your data is sortedd - no, you can't really avoid a linear scan. If you have sorted data, *then* you can employ a binary search.

Comment: What type of efficiency are you after? IE. run-time performance vs. code size vs. human readability vs. maintainability?

Comment: Consider using the array `find` method

Comment: You can create a dictionary where the key is concatenated name and hair color and value is a list of matching entries, then get entries by key. But it is worth do something like this only if you have a lot of entries and also you need to find them quickly and many times.